# Can't able to install `qrcode` npm module

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I was trying to install `qrcode` npm module in my project to read `qrcode`. My system environment is `windows7`. I have followed this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gyp) to setup. After I installed pre-required softwares, I was trying to install `qrcode`module but it's throwing an error. please check below.

```
 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\src\win_delay_load_hook.c(34): error C2373: '__pfnDliNotifyHook2': redefinition; different type modifiers [D:\Practice\loopbackPractice\EMployeeDetails\node_modules\qrcode\node_modules\canvas\build\ca
nvas.vcxproj]
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\delayimp.h(134): note: see declaration of '__pfnDliNotifyHook2'
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe`  failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Practice\loopbackPractice\EMployeeDetails\node_modules\qrcode\node_modules\canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "qrcode" "--save"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! canvas@1.3.16 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.3.16 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs canvas
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Practice\loopbackPractice\EMployeeDetails\npm-debug.log
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same problem installing on a mac as well